# Object is not updated in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, spinner

I am doing an android project, trying to work with fragment

one of my fragments has a spinner which I need a separate listener for it

when I set the listener I send an object to the constructor as I need this object I don't know why I get null all the time when I call it in the fragment while it's updated in the listener

maybe I have to use another way to pass objects, but I didnt found any

I will be appreciated if you can help me to know why [chosenTrackable] is null in the fragment all the time ? 
and if there is a better way to call object between fragments and listeners

here is my code :

```
public class AddTracking extends Fragment {
    Spinner trackableSpinner;
    Context context;
    HashMap <Integer, MyTrackable> myTrackables ;
    MyTrackable chosenTrackable;
    private static final String TAG = "AddTracking";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        context = container.getContext();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_tracking, container, false);

        myTrackables= new Model(view.getContext()).getTrackables();

        //initilizing
        trackableSpinner =   view.findViewById(R.id.trackable_spinner);

        //setup trackable spinner
        ArrayAdapter trackableSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new ArrayList<>(myTrackables.values()));
        trackableSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        trackableSpinner.setAdapter(trackableSpinnerAdapter);
        trackableSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener( new SpinnerTrackableItemSelectedListener(this.getActivity(),chosenTrackable));




        chosenTrackable = myTrackables.get(trackableSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView:  " + chosenTrackable);
         return view;
    }
}
```

listner:

```
public class SpinnerTrackableItemSelectedListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
Context  context ;
private static final String TAG = "SpinnerTrackableItemSel";
MyTrackable chosenTrackable;

public SpinnerTrackableItemSelectedListener(Context context, MyTrackable chosenTrackable) {
    this.context = context;
    this.chosenTrackable = chosenTrackable ;
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    chosenTrackable = (MyTrackable) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
 Log.d(TAG, "loadTimeSpinner: " + chosenTrackable);

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}




}
```

Comment: did you still get null after you select an option from spinner?

Comment: yes it is still null

Comment: onItem Selected listener is only invoked when you newly selected adapter position is different as the previous position.